# fuzzy matching millions of records

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, bigdata, fuzzywuzzy

I am trying do a fuzzy matching between two columns in which col="co_zip22" will iterate through all the rows in col="co_zip23" and will find a match with a match score
So basically co_zip is a unique key which I have created combining company name and zip column and I am trying to find out if a company from 2022 is present in our 2023 recordor not.

I have made a file which consists of two columns containg the co_zip22 and co_zip23 to do the fuzzy match.
We don't have any unique identifiers so I can created a string with company name and zip
Below is my code and it's working fine for small records but it's keep on running for such a big data set and it has been running for 2 days now

```
similarity = []
for i in df.co_zip22:#full
        ratio = process.extract( i, df.co_zip23, limit=1)
        similarity.append(ratio[0][1])

df['similarity'] = pd.Series(similarity)
df.head(3)
```

Comment: Doing a fuzzy match from every record to every other record is inherently slow. You need to do something to restrict the match, e.g. only doing the similarity score with elements which have a similar [Soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) code. Without having an example of the kind of fuzzy matches you're trying to make, I don't know how to suggest a filtering step that doesn't result in false negatives.

Comment: rapidfuzz is written in C++ language and because of this, it's faster than fuzzywuzzy.